# What is the probability that you will not choose 3 different numbers out of 10 digits 12 times.

Tags: probability

You are given numbers 0-9 and after a random number generator, end up with 112556678889. Notice that 0, 3, and 4 were never given. What is the probability that 12 times, all three of those numbers weren't given?
Is this the correct way to solve it:
(3/10)^12

Comment: Are you asking specifically about $0,3,4$ being missing or some three digits being missing?  Does it count if four digits are missing?  You have to make the question clear to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it's $(\frac{7}{10})^{12}$
This is for the specific for 3 specific digits to not be included. Therefore to omit them, we have 7 out of 10 choices each digit in the 12 length string. Someone correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: That is correct if we want to exclude a specific set of three numbers and having more numbers missing would be acceptable.  OP has not clarified what the question is.